A movie surrounding WW1 following soldiers 3 'main characters'
The movie was watched late at night (if it even is a movie).
I believe there are three characters each with individual stories - with the last two characters as an exception.
The first person is an Australian soldier who deserts his regiments, and finds himself at a French farm with an older unhappily-married French woman. He falls in love with, and has an affair with her. Later on he turns himself in, and is sentenced to death by shooting squad, but ends up never being executed because the war ends.
The two last characters have a close connection. They are both soldiers, but enemies. The first one is British and the second German. You follow the story of each of them and their daily lives in the trenches, and how much they wish for the war to end. They meet in the very last moments of the movie when they're supposed to fix a barbed wire fence for each of their respective sides. They see each other, and kill each other, in the very moment that the war ends.
